Border of div around input type text and select tag for html not fitting

The border when set to fit-content doesn't wrap around the end of the bar. Same thing happens with my select tag.
.wrap-around {
  position   : relative;
  display    : flex;
  width      : auto;
  max-width  : fit-content;
  background : linear-gradient(to bottom right, var(--transparent-orange), var(--yellow-layer));
  padding    : 3px 3px;
}


Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site help section useful when it comes to asking a good question. To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a minimal reproducible example. Here's a question checklist you might find useful...
